# How to make TypeScript not default to readonly for arrays in interfaces?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, native, readonly

How can I disable the default readonly that comes with typescript?

I have the following interface which in turn has an array of another interface (buttonListData), this causes typescript to default to readonly for the whole array, but this generates an error in vscode in the components

```
import { proxy } from 'valtio'

export interface ItemType {
  id: string
  name: string
  level: number
  status?: string[]
  identity: {
    adjective: string
    faction: string
    rarity: string
  }
}

export type ButtonListActionBarType = {
  status: 'active' | 'disabled' | 'default'
  button: 'enemies' | 'gates' | 'info'
  title?: string
  content?: {
    type: 'list',
    data: ItemType[]
  }
}

export interface ActionBarStateType {
  activeButton: 'enemies' | 'gates' | 'info'
  buttonListData: Array<ButtonListActionBarType>
  buttonsTop: boolean
  contentData?: object
  isOpen: boolean
  position: 'left' | 'right'
  show: boolean
}

const state = proxy<ActionBarStateType>({})

export default state
```

the component with the error is as follows and the error:

```
import React from 'react'
import HomeTemplate from '../../components/templates/homeTemplate'
import { useSnapshot } from 'valtio'
import store from '../../state/store'
import { Hud, MainContainer } from '../../components/layouts'

const Home = () => {
  const actionBarState = useSnapshot(store.state.actionBar)

  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <Hud actionBar={actionBarState} /> {/* <-- here the error */}
      <HomeTemplate />
    </MainContainer>
  )
}

export default Home
```

interface Hud Component:

```
export interface HudProps {
  actionBar: ActionBarStateType
}
```

and the error:

```
Type '{ readonly activeButton: "enemies" | "gates" | "info"; readonly buttonListData: readonly { readonly status: "default" | "active" | "disabled"; readonly button: "enemies" | "gates" | "info"; readonly title?: string | undefined; readonly content?: { ...; } | undefined; }[]; ... 4 more ...; readonly show: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionBarStateType'.

  Types of property 'buttonListData' are incompatible.

    The type 'readonly { readonly status: "default" | "active" | "disabled"; readonly button: "enemies" | "gates" | "info"; readonly title?: string | undefined; readonly content?: { readonly type: "list"; readonly data: readonly { ...; }[]; } | undefined; }[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'ButtonListActionBarType[]'.ts(2322)

Hud.tsx(9, 3): The expected type comes from property 'actionBar' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HudProps'
```

here you can see that it defaults to adding readonly to the array, which is exactly what the error specifies [image]

I am testing all this in react native and I have no problems in displaying the data on the mobile, I have also compared the data with the interface and there are no extra parameters that could influence the error.

I have tried to change from this `Array<ButtonListActionBarType>` to this: `ButtonListActionBarType[]` but the error persists.

here are some links I have visited:

[issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42357)

I got the following code from the link above, but I don't know if it's correct

```
const tup1 = [1, 2]                    // readonly [number, number]
const tup2: [number, number] = [1, 2]  // [number, number]
const tup3 = [1, 2] as mut             // [number, number]
const tup4 = tup3 as const             // readonly [number, number]
```

Comment: ① Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) ② `const tup1 = [1, 2] // readonly [number, number]`  uhh, [I don't think so](https://tsplay.dev/w6GZeN). When you [edit] to fix the screenshots, would you also make sure your code is a [mre] that actually demonstrates what you're talking about?  Otherwise it's harder to help.

Comment: The interfaces you showed will not create a type definition that includes `readonly`. My guess is that the code in `useActionBar` is the problem. Perhaps you're intending for it to make and return a `ActionBarStateType`, but it isn't actually doing so. Can you show us that code?

Comment: TypeScript **doesn't** default to read-only for arrays, and the example you give at the end is incorrect. For instance, the type of `tup1` in `const tup1 = [1, 2]` is **not** `readonly [number, number]`, it's `number[]`.https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHAjDAvDA2sgNDATALoDcAUAPTkzUwB6A-EA It would only be `readonly` if you had `as const` on it (https://tsplay.dev/w8Y7dN), and then it would be `readonly [1, 2]`, not `readonly [number, number]`. Re the linked issue, it's *suggesting* making things immutable by default, not complaining TypeScript does that.

Comment: added the `useActionBar` code to the body

Comment: This still doesn't look like a [mre], unfortunately.  If I paste all your code into a standalone IDE [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w29ZrW) I get a bunch of errors, none of which you seem to be asking about.  If you make it easier for others to demonstrate the issue, you'll make it more likely to get help.  Otherwise there's a barrier for others to overcome and they may either fail or decline to do so.  I think I'll disengage now. Good luck!